# Multiple tables, multiple statement

Tags: php, mysql

Let's take 3 tables that has all tons of rows:

```
TABLE Posts

PostPID
PostUID
PostText

TABLE Users

UserUID
UserName

TABLE Favorites

FavoriteUID
FavoritePID
```

Now, in order to get all the recent posts I perform a query such as:

```
SELECT p.PostPID, p.PostUID, p.PostText, u.UserUID, u.UserName
    FROM Posts AS p
        JOIN Users AS u
        ON p.PostUID = u.UserUID
    ORDER BY p.PostPID DESC
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

Which works fine. Now I was wondering, how could I get only the posts a certain UserUID prefers? So only the one with `FavoriteUID = UserUID = X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery.

```
...
Where p.PostUID in (select f.FavoritePID from Favorite f where f.FavoriteUID = UserUID)
...
```

Comment: You should use the join as suggested below.  I missed the "tons" of records part.  Subquery will be slow in this case.

Comment: agree. IN operation is more expensive

Answer (score 2):

second join will do the same

```
SELECT 
  p.PostPID, p.PostUID, p.PostText, u.UserUID, u.UserName
FROM 
  Posts AS p
JOIN 
  Users AS u ON p.PostUID = u.UserUID
Join 
  Favorites as f on f.FavoriteUID = u.UserUID and f.FavoritePID=p.PostPID
ORDER 
  BY p.PostPID DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```